# JSF Primefaces redirect to the new tab on dataTable doubleclick

Tags: redirect, jsf, primefaces

I try to redirect to the **NEW TAB** on PrimeFaces dataTable row double click event. My example works only for redirection in the current tab, but I need to redirect to the new one.

My PrimeFaces datatable:

```html
            <p:dataTable var="item"
                         scrollable="true"
                         scrollHeight="100%"
                         scrollWidth="100%"
                         showGridlines="true"
                         selectionMode="single"
                         selection="#{docsBean.docEntitySelected}"
                         rowKey="#{item.id}"
                         value="#{docsBean.loadDocsList()}">

                <p:ajax event="rowDblselect"  listener="#{docsBean.rowDblSelect}"/>
```

My Bean event:

```
    public void rowDblSelect(SelectEvent<DocEntity> event) throws IOException {

        docEntitySelected = event.getObject();

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("unitDocument.xhtml?docId=" + docEntitySelected.getId());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```java
PrimeRequestContext.getCurrentInstance()
    .getScriptsToExecute()
    .add("window.open('unitDocument.xhtml?docId=" + docEntitySelected.getId()+"', '_newtab')");
```